# how to remove _(underscore) from file name from file upload in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, xls

I am trying to upload a file and rename that file to include the folder name, and the folder name contains white space.

After I added the folder name to filename the output filename now includes `'_'` characters.

How can I remove those `_`?

I am doing it like this

```
$new_name = $album.' PF';
$config['file_name'] = $new_name;
```

I am getting the filename back like this

```
GAYATRI_EDUCATIONAL_SOCIETY_PF.xls
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$name="the_first_image.jpeg";
str_replace("_", "", $name);
```

will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)** to remove _ form file name as

```
$str="GAYATRI_EDUCATIONAL_SOCIETY_PF.xls";
echo str_replace("_", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` to find and replace from string.

```
$new_name = $album.' PF';
$new_name = str_replace('_', '', $new_name);
$config['file_name'] = $new_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try String Replace Function Of Php

```
$config['file_name']  =     str_replace("_", "",$new_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple,

Use `str_replace` PHP function

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

example - `$new_name = str_replace('_', '', $new_name);`

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely do the magic

execute this code in the terminal

find . -type f -name '._*' -delete